# An elegant proof for a claim about orthogonal and positive-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, positive-semidefinite, orthogonal-matrices

Let $P$ be a real $n \times n$ symmetric positive-semidefinite matrix.

Suppose that $\langle O,P \rangle = \langle I,P \rangle$ for some orthogonal matrix $O$. Here $\langle , \rangle$ is the Euclidean (Frobenius) inner product. The assumption is equivalent to $\text{tr}(O^TP)=\text{tr}(P)$.

**Then $OP=P$ holds.** Since we can replace $O$ with $O^T$ the claim is equivalent to the seemingly surprising assertion $\text{tr}(OP)=\text{tr}(P) \implies OP=P$.

> I have a proof, and I wonder whether there are other shorter proofs.
>   Is there a proof which does not require diagonalizing $P$?

---

Here is my proof: By orthogonally diagonalizing $P$, we can reduce to the case where $P=\Sigma$ is diagonal, with non-negative entries $\sigma_i$.

The assumption implies $\sum_i \sigma_i O_{ii}=\sum_i \sigma_i$ where the sums run over all the indices $i$ where $\sigma_i \neq 0$. Since $|O_{ii}| \le 1$ this forces $O_{ii}=1$ for all these $i$. A direct check then implies that $O\Sigma=\Sigma$:

Indeed, $O\Sigma=\Sigma$ is equivalent to $O_{ij}\sigma_j=\Sigma_{ij}$.
If  $\sigma_j=0$, then $\Sigma_{ij}=0$ so equality holds. If $\sigma_j \neq 0$, then $O_{jj}=1$ so equality holds for $i=j$. For $i \neq j$,  $\Sigma_{ij}=0$ (since $\Sigma$ is diagonal) and , and $O_{ij}=0$, since whenever $O_{jj}=1$, all the rest of the entries in the $j$-th column of $O$ are zero. (Since $O$ is orthogonal).

Comment: A possibly helpful reformulation: if $A$ is **not** positive semidefinite, then $\operatorname{tr}(A) < \operatorname{tr}(|A|)$, where $|A|:= \sqrt{A^TA}$.

Comment: Another thought is that the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) might be useful here.  That is, we have
$$
2\langle O,P \rangle = 
\langle P+O,P+O \rangle - \langle P,P \rangle - \langle O,O \rangle
$$

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice reformulation. Unfortunately I don't see how it helps getting a simpler proof. (I also don't really see a way to use polarization as you suggested). I guess the current proofs are good enough, and we should not expect for more...

Comment: I agree, I couldn't really think of a way forward.  Interesting question, anyway.

Comment: Am I seeing it right that this is the equality of the inequality $\operatorname{tr}\left(OP\right) \leq \operatorname{tr}P$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, that is exactly what you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following proof does diagonalize $P$, but not in matrix form.

Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal eigenbasis of $P$ and $Pv_i=\lambda_iv_i$ for each $i$. Then
$$
\langle P,I\rangle
= \langle P,O\rangle = \sum_i\langle Pv_i,Ov_i\rangle
\le \sum_i\|Pv_i\|\|Ov_i\|
= \sum_i\lambda_i
= \operatorname{tr}(P)
= \langle P,I\rangle.
$$
Therefore $\langle Pv_i,Ov_i\rangle=\|Pv_i\|\|Ov_i\|$ for each $i$. Since $Pv_i=\lambda v_i$ and $Ov_i$ is a unit vector, we have $\langle v_i,Ov_i\rangle=1$ and in turn $Ov_i=v_i$ whenever $\lambda_i>0$. Hence $OP$ and $P$ agree on $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, meaning that $OP=P$.

Comment: The second proof in my original answer is wrong. $K^2$ is negative semidefinite, but $K^4$ apriori is not.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I also came up with this proof before. I see it as "morally equivalent" to the proof with explicit matrix diagonalization. I will accept your answer if no better ones will appear.

Comment: Another minor comment: I have inspected again my original proof (which was identical to yours). Since $P$ is only assumed semi-definite, then it can have zero eigenvalues. When $\lambda_i=0$, we have $Pv_i=0$, so we cannot conclude anything about $Ov_i$ from the C-S inequality. However, that does not change the end result $OP=P$, since in this equality, $O$ is only "tested" (or evaluated) against vectors which lie outside $\ker P$.

Answer (score 2):

Trace is invariant under cyclic permutations, so $$\mathrm{tr}(O^TP)=\mathrm{tr}(P^{1/2}O^TP^{1/2})=\langle OP^{1/2},P^{1/2}\rangle.$$
Letting $\|\cdot\|$ denote the Frobenius norm, one form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says that

$$\langle O,P\rangle=\langle OP^{1/2},P^{1/2}\rangle\leq \|OP^{1/2}\|\cdot\|P^{1/2}\|=\mathrm{tr}(P)^{1/2}\mathrm{tr}(P)^{1/2}=\langle I,P\rangle$$
with equality only when

$$OP^{1/2}=P^{1/2}\frac{\|OP^{1/2}\|}{\|P^{1/2}\|}=P^{1/2}.$$
Multiplying on the right by $P^{1/2},$ this condition implies
$$OP=P.$$